# JS: I need 3 headings to require a click/heading to turn blue in color. EventListener question

Tags: javascript, event-listener

[Image of Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mgDJ.jpg)

Hi, following functionality is needed.

1. Click once anywhere on document/Webpage, first heading turns blue; other two headings stay black.
2. Click again anywhere on document/Webpage, second heading turns blue; 3rd heading stays black.
3. Click again anywhere on document/Webpage, second heading turns blue.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">   <title> test </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>

  <h1 class="heading"> click once on webpage/document, I turn blue</h1>
  <h4 class="heading"> click twice on webpage/document, I turn blue</h4>
  <h5 class="heading"> click thrice on webpage/document, I turn blue</h5>

  <script src="index.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS Code:

```
const total = document.querySelectorAll(".heading").length;

for (let i = 0; i < total; i++) {
  document.addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.querySelectorAll(".heading")[i].style.color = "blue";
  });

}
```

for loop isn't working as expected; what am I doing wrong. Help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way, by keeping track of the index you're at:

```js
const $headings = document.querySelectorAll(".heading");
let i = 0;

document.addEventListener("click", changeNextTitle);

function changeNextTitle() {
  $headings[i].style.color = 'blue';
  i++;
  if (i >= $headings.length) {
    document.removeEventListener("click", changeNextTitle);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="heading"> click once on webpage/document, I turn blue</h1>
<h4 class="heading"> click twice on webpage/document, I turn blue</h4>
<h5 class="heading"> click thrice on webpage/document, I turn blue</h5>
```

Comment: Thanks @blex. It did work the way I wanted to. Since I'm a beginner, may I ask what is this $. Is it JQeury or just name of a Constant and could have been something else as well.
Also, does this mean the only thing my code missed was the removal of EventListener?
I would hightly appreciate if you could comment on this. I would love to learn the flowchart, how is your code working is making me curious! Thanks and best regards!

Comment: @mrnothing The `$` could have been anything else. I just like to use it as a convention in  the name of variables containing DOM elements (HTML elements). The removal of the event listener is not required, it's just cleaner to remove it once you don't need it. The problem in your code was the `for` loop. You added the event listener 3 times, once for each heading. So when you clicked once, all 3 listeners were triggered at the same time, and all 3 headings changed.

Comment: In this version, we initialize `i` at `0`, globally. And we add the event listener once. Every time you click, it changes the color of the heading at index `i`, and increments it. Until we have no more headings to change, then it removes the event listener (it stops listening for clicks)

Comment: Thank you very much @blex for your comments and info. 
Can we not at all use achieve this functionality using for loop? Because we are actually using a loop here anyway, no?

Comment: It's _sort of_ a loop, but with a big difference compared to `for`, `while` and `forEach` loops: it's asynchronous. Which means that you have to wait for a click before running the next iteration

Comment: all I want to learn is, that why this code is working? It is not even a loop, is it?
Because we did not specify at which point should the index be incremented. Kindly point towards that point otherwise:

const arrayHeadings = document.querySelectorAll(".heading");
let i = 0;
document.addEventListener("click", changeNextTitle);
function changeNextTitle() {
  arrayHeadings[i].style.color = 'blue';
  i++;
}

Comment: _"we did not specify at which point should the index be incremented"_ We did, right where it says `i++`. You could say it's a loop, even though it's not a conventionnal one. If you _really_ want to use a loop, here is a trick using Promises and async/await, but that's a whole other subject: https://jsfiddle.net/d0gaymz9/

Comment: Thank you Sir. I really appreciate your help. I'll definitely look asynch loops up. 
Sorry what I wanted to say before was, "we did not specify after last line of code (i++) that how the further execution should proceed? In loops, the same lines of codes iterate. I did not see where we tell computer to go back to detecting click and put i++. If we say after last line the code starts from beginning, then we can see that i = 0 in beginning. And should not increment the index. I think I should definitely look into Asynch loop sir. You have helped enough. God bless you!